# Analytics for Apache Hadoop not visible in IBM Bluemix, why?

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I am trying to run Hadoop Ibm Biginsights, but ibm bluemix not display.

Details:  I have registered (free trail) and login into ibm bluemix, but unfortunately in Service category, Analytics for Hadoop not appear in the bigdata session. please find the preview here.

I am following [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-analytics-for-hadoop1/index.html) to practice.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the United Kingdom region? IBM Analytics for Hadoop service is currently only available in the US-South region. You can change the region to US-South in the top right corner of the page.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I am in UK region, Thanks problem resolved.

Comment: Great! If your problem is resolved, you can mark it as the answer by clicking the green check mark :)